# React native file uploading

Tags: android, ios, file-upload, react-native

How can I get access to the file system in React Native for both Android and iOS? (like `<input type="file">` in web)? I know `CameraRoll` method, but it is used only for images and I need to upload text files also.

Comment: Have you had a look at https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs ?

Comment: You can try https://github.com/g6ling/react-native-uploader

Comment: Unfortunately react-native-uploader don't work with latest react versions